# Babel option shorthands=off fails to render French typography

Tags: r, latex, bookdown

I'm using bookdown to render my thesis, which I've written in French. The default rendering process of bookdown transforms markdown in LaTeX using the babel option `<code>shorthands=off</code>`. The use of this option fails to render French typography, such as a fine space before **';'**, **'»'** or **':'**, and fine space after **'«'**.

Does anyone know how to activate shorthands for babel?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Indeed, `bookdown`  uses `system.file("rmd", "latex", "default-1.17.0.2.tex", package = "rmarkdown")` as template, which has the babel option `shorthands=off` hardwired. I would do the following:

- Copy the (renamed) template: `file.copy(system.file("rmd", "latex", "default-1.17.0.2.tex", package = "rmarkdown"), "templatex.tex")`
- Edit `template.tex` to remove `shorthands=off,`.
- Edit `_output.yml` to include `template: template.tex` in the `bookdown::pdf_book` section.